# My close button for my modal is not working

Tags: javascript

Hello the code that I got from w3 school only works for one image but I have multiple images on my webpage how would I use an array with a for loop? Please help I have been stuck for hours. I have an idea but this involves multiple functions would I use a switch statement to get the image id?
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

Here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sfL71epx/
Click the Second Image
The html is hidden for some reason it shows when i edit. Let me know if you know why.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">



  <div class="row text-center text-lg-left">

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/pWkk7iiCoDM/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail " id="myImg" src="https://source.unsplash.com/aob0ukAYfuI/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
      <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/EUfxH-pze7s/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/M185_qYH8vg/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/sesveuG_rNo/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/AvhMzHwiE_0/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/2gYsZUmockw/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/EMSDtjVHdQ8/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/8mUEy0ABdNE/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/G9Rfc1qccH4/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/aJeH0KcFkuc/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/p2TQ-3Bh3Oo/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your complete code including html please?

Comment: The html is hidden for some reason

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sfL71epx/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the click event listener which actually opens the modal is just attached to a single image - the one from the w3schools example. You need to attach it to every image.
Luckily things aren't that hard though. All of your images share the same class **img-fluid img-thumbnail**. Using a handy Javascript function called **getElementsByClassName()** we can get an array of all the images on your site, that share that particular class.
After that's done, you just need to loop over the array it returns and attach the click listeners to each one.

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("img-fluid img-thumbnail");
for (var a = 0; a < images.length; a++) {
  images[a].onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }
}
```

Here's a live demo:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("img-fluid img-thumbnail");
for (var a = 0; a < images.length; a++) {
  images[a].onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }
}
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Clean Blog v5.0.5 (https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/clean-blog)
 * Copyright 2013-2019 Start Bootstrap
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-clean-blog/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

body {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #212529;
  font-family: Lora, 'Times New Roman', serif
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 30px 0
}

p a {
  text-decoration: underline
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
}

a {
  color: #212529;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s
}

a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #0085a1
}

blockquote {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #868e96
}

.section-heading {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 60px
}

.caption {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: italic;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px
}

::selection {
  color: #fff;
  background: #0085a1;
  text-shadow: none
}

img::selection {
  color: #fff;
  background: 0 0
}

img::-moz-selection {
  color: #fff;
  background: 0 0
}

#mainNav {
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9ecef;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
}

#mainNav .navbar-brand {
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #343a40
}

#mainNav .navbar-toggler {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #343a40
}

#mainNav .navbar-nav>li.nav-item>a {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

@media only screen and (min-width:992px) {
  #mainNav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    background: 0 0
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-brand {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #fff
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-brand:focus,
  #mainNav .navbar-brand:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8)
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-nav>li.nav-item>a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #fff
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-nav>li.nav-item>a:focus,
  #mainNav .navbar-nav>li.nav-item>a:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8)
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:992px) {
  #mainNav {
    -webkit-transition: background-color .2s;
    transition: background-color .2s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden
  }
  #mainNav.is-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: -67px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s;
    transition: -webkit-transform .2s;
    transition: transform .2s;
    transition: transform .2s, -webkit-transform .2s;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9)
  }
  #mainNav.is-fixed .navbar-brand {
    color: #212529
  }
  #mainNav.is-fixed .navbar-brand:focus,
  #mainNav.is-fixed .navbar-brand:hover {
    color: #0085a1
  }
  #mainNav.is-fixed .navbar-nav>li.nav-item>a {
    color: #212529
  }
  #mainNav.is-fixed .navbar-nav>li.nav-item>a:focus,
  #mainNav.is-fixed .navbar-nav>li.nav-item>a:hover {
    color: #0085a1
  }
  #mainNav.is-visible {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0)
  }
}

header.masthead {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background: no-repeat center center;
  background-color: #868e96;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover
}

header.masthead .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ca5981;
  opacity: .5;
}

header.masthead .page-heading,
header.masthead .post-heading,
header.masthead .site-heading {
  padding: 200px 0 150px;
  color: #fff
}

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
  header.masthead .page-heading,
  header.masthead .post-heading,
  header.masthead .site-heading {
    padding: 200px 0
  }
}

header.masthead .page-heading,
header.masthead .site-heading {
  text-align: center
}

header.masthead .page-heading h1,
header.masthead .site-heading h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 0
}

header.masthead .page-heading .subheading,
header.masthead .site-heading .subheading {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.1;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
  header.masthead .page-heading h1,
  header.masthead .site-heading h1 {
    font-size: 80px
  }
}

header.masthead .post-heading h1 {
  font-size: 35px
}

header.masthead .post-heading .meta,
header.masthead .post-heading .subheading {
  line-height: 1.1;
  display: block
}

header.masthead .post-heading .subheading {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 10px 0 30px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
}

header.masthead .post-heading .meta {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: Lora, 'Times New Roman', serif
}

header.masthead .post-heading .meta a {
  color: #fff
}

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
  header.masthead .post-heading h1 {
    font-size: 55px
  }
  header.masthead .post-heading .subheading {
    font-size: 30px
  }
}

.post-preview>a {
  color: #212529
}

.post-preview>a:focus,
.post-preview>a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0085a1
}

.post-preview>a>.post-title {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}

.post-preview>a>.post-subtitle {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0 0 10px
}

.post-preview>.post-meta {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #868e96
}

.post-preview>.post-meta>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #212529
}

.post-preview>.post-meta>a:focus,
.post-preview>.post-meta>a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #0085a1
}

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .post-preview>a>.post-title {
    font-size: 36px
  }
}

.floating-label-form-group {
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: .5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6
}

.floating-label-form-group input,
.floating-label-form-group textarea {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0;
  resize: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: 0 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  font-family: Lora, 'Times New Roman', serif
}

.floating-label-form-group input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.floating-label-form-group textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #868e96;
  font-family: Lora, 'Times New Roman', serif
}

.floating-label-form-group label {
  font-size: .85em;
  line-height: 1.764705882em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 2em;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transition: top .3s ease, opacity .3s ease;
  transition: top .3s ease, opacity .3s ease;
  vertical-align: middle;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  opacity: 0
}

.floating-label-form-group .help-block {
  margin: 15px 0
}

.floating-label-form-group-with-value label {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1
}

.floating-label-form-group-with-focus label {
  color: #0085a1
}

form .form-group:first-child .floating-label-form-group {
  border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6
}

footer {
  padding: 50px 0 65px
}

footer .list-inline {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

footer .copyright {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center
}

.btn {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: #0085a1;
  border-color: #0085a1
}

.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00657b !important;
  border-color: #00657b !important
}

.btn-lg {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 25px 35px
}

body>div:nth-child(3)>ul {
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flexbox;
  list-style-type: none;
}

body>div:nth-child(3)>ul>li {
  border: 2px solid #e485a5;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}

body>div:nth-child(3)>ul>li:hover {
  border: 2px solid aqua;
  background-color: #e485a5;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation: flip 3s linear 0s infinite normal;
  animation: flip 3s linear 0s infinite normal;
}

body>div:nth-child(3)>ul>li:nth-child(3),
body>div:nth-child(3)>ul>li:nth-child(4) {
  border: 2px solid #e485a5;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

body>div:nth-child(3)>ul>li:nth-child(3):hover,
body>div:nth-child(3)>ul>li:nth-child(4):hover {
  border: 2px solid #e485a5;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  border: 2px solid aqua;
  background-color: #e485a5;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flip {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(180);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes flip {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}

#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">



  <div class="row text-center text-lg-left">

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
                  <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://powermovesandpumps.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Walking-through-Kuta-Bali-2-300x400.jpg" alt="">
                </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
                  <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail " id="myImg" src="http://powermovesandpumps.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/IMG_4082-768x512.jpg" alt="">
                </a>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
      <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
                  <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/EUfxH-pze7s/400x300" alt="">
                </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
                  <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/M185_qYH8vg/400x300" alt="">
                </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
                  <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/sesveuG_rNo/400x300" alt="">
                </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
                  <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/AvhMzHwiE_0/400x300" alt="">
                </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
                  <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/2gYsZUmockw/400x300" alt="">
                </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
                  <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/EMSDtjVHdQ8/400x300" alt="">
                </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
                  <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/8mUEy0ABdNE/400x300" alt="">
                </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
                  <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/G9Rfc1qccH4/400x300" alt="">
                </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
                  <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/aJeH0KcFkuc/400x300" alt="">
                </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
                  <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/p2TQ-3Bh3Oo/400x300" alt="">
                </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```